# VersionControl_Git package not found

Tags: php, git, mamp-pro

when trying to execute a phing build on a macOS with MAMP PRO, I get a message that the pear git package is not installed.

message looks like:
The Git tasks depend on PEAR\'s VersionControl_Git package.

but is I type:

```
pear list-files versioncontrol_git
```

I get:

```
Installed Files For versioncontrol_git
======================================
Type Install Path
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Object/Blob.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Object/Commit.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Object/Tree.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Util/Command.php
php /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Util/RevListFetcher.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Component.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Object.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git/Exception.php
php  /Users/nick/pear/share/pear/VersionControl/Git.php
doc  /Users/nick/pear/docs/VersionControl_Git/doc/versioncontrol-git.xml
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/checkFixtures.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_GitTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_ObjectTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_Object_CommitTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_Util_CommandTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/README
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_ComponentTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_Object_BlobTest.php
test /Users/nick/pear/tests/VersionControl_Git/tests/VersionControl_Git_Object_TreeTest.php
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [PEAR installation instructions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php)

> ### Verifying the include path
>
> To use PEAR and PEAR compatible packages in your applications, you normally include them into your PHP scripts using `require_once()`.
> **For this to work, PEAR's `php_dir` must be a part of PHP's include path.**

Check if, by following those steps, you can get your build to work.